# The import java.util.Vector cannot be resolved JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jax-rs, jetty, java-11

I'm developing a jax-rs oauth server with JDK11 and Java 11 support.
When I redirect the user to my oauthForm.jsp, the jsp compiler fails to compile the form with the current error:

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The import java.util.Vector cannot be resolved

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
java.util.Vector cannot be resolved to a type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
_jspx_dependants cannot be resolved
```

Surprisingly I don't use the Vector class in my jsp:

```
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.OAuthAuthorizationData"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.OAuthPermission" %>
<%-- <%@ page import="java.util.*" %> --%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Vector" %>

<%

    OAuthAuthorizationData data = (OAuthAuthorizationData)request.getAttribute("oauthauthorizationdata");
%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

</html>
```

The Vector import is there only because I added it in an attempt to fix the: java.util.Vector cannot be resolved error.

Comment: Is that the entire JSP, or did you omit the actual JSP contents?

Comment: It's the entire jsp, i stripped out the contents and the error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this by upgrading from

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>6.1.15</version>
          <configuration>
              <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

To

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.15.v20190215</version>
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The service now works, but I get a lot of warning like this regarding javax.servlet during the start phase:

```
[WARNING] javax.servlet.ServletConfig scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///home/froggo/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.class, jar:file:///home/froggo/sorgenti/link_it/govauth/govauth/target/services/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.class
[WARNING] javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///home/froggo/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.class, jar:file:///home/froggo/sorgenti/link_it/govauth/govauth/target/services/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.class
```